# How to remove the dependencies section from nuspec file in the generated nuget package using msbuild 15

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuspec, msbuild-15

I use msbuild  v15.8.168.64424 (vs 2017.8)  commandline to build nuget package for console application. I used ILMerge to merge all dependencies, so I get only one exe file without dependencies.

When runing the command

```
        msbuild project1.csproj /t:build /p:configuration=release /p:IsTool=true
```

I get the nuget package, but when inspecting it, I find the `dependencies section`.

```
     <dependencies>
           <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5">
            <dependency id="lib1" version="1.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
            <dependency id="lib2" version="2.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />              
          </group>
        </dependencies>
```

I want the `dependencies section to be empty (because I merged all the dependencies).

I can use nuspec file to generate the package without dependencies section, but the drawback is passing manually  all the metadata which is included in csproj.
I didn't find a property for the dependencies in [pack target inputs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target-inputs)

**The Question:**

How I remove the dependencies section from the nuspec file which is included in the generated nuget package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the metadata `PrivateAssets="All"` on the package or project references  (`<PackageReference>` / `<ProjectReference>`) in the csproj file to exclude them as NuGet dependencies.

Note that this change needs a restore so perform a NuGet restore in between or add `-restore` to the MSBuild invocation.

Comment: did you build with an added `-restore` parameter or perform a NuGet restore in between?

Comment: Thanks @Martin, yeeees, it's working with -restore. kindly can you explain this in your answer.